# Set title of preselected values of Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I attached preselected values of [Select2](https://select2.org) using AJAX like below.

```
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/wordpressbosta/matt/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            // url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
              element_id: element_id,
              action: 'get_preselect_values',
            },
          }).then(function (data) {
            var options = [];

            if (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index,text) {
                options.push(new Option(text['text'], text['id'], true, true));
              });
            }
                
            selectEle.append(options).trigger('change');
         }
```

I would like to set `title` of preselected values.

[image]

I tried with below code.

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
              element_id: element_id,
              action: 'get_preselect_values',
            },
          }).then(function (data) {
            var options = [];

            if (data) {
              $.each(data, function (index,text) {

                var user_data = '<table> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td>Organisation</td> \
                    <td>'+text[0][1]+'</td> \
                  </tr> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td>Age</td> \
                    <td>'+ text[0][0]+'</td> \
                  </tr> \
                </table>';


                var opt = new Option(text['text'], text['id'], true, true);                
                opt.attr("title",user_data);
                options.push(opt);
              });
            }
            
            selectEle.trigger('change');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? What problems have you encountered with that attempt?

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. I edited my post. Please check it again. Thanks.

Comment: And the problem now is what exactly? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas. Yes, may be I couldn't express my self properly. Sorry for that. Thanks.

Comment: you're trying to set a table as title .... I don;t know if that can work.....

Comment: Thanks @RaoDYC. Actually this `table` is working fine in currently selected values. But I would like to use this `table` for preselected values (which will stay there before current selection) which will fetch from database using AJAX. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to set the content inside of <td> in user_data variable as title then fetch that and set as title.... but if want to set the whole table as title.....that may not going to work

Comment: Thanks @RaoDYC. But this `table` is working fine now with current selection of select2. I need to set `title` of preselected values of select2. `ttile` can be anything for now.

Comment: Actually, I would not pass the whole table in attribute `title`, instead I would just pass the related data and construct the table later with the `title` data. That way you don't need store every `tables` in each attribute.

Comment: Thanks @RaoDYC. I made another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70850966/how-to-template-preselected-values-of-select2. Could you please check it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try method of select2 when an item is selected

```
$('#example').on('select2:select', function (e) { 
    $(this).attr('title', 'some value title');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Comanici Bogdan. I used these for current selection and these are working fine now. But I would like to set `title` for preselected values which will come from database using AJAX.

Comment: Post the data you get from db and data use on values with select2

Comment: Thanks @Comanici Bogdan. Do you need code ?

Comment: Try: $('#mySelect2').append(opt).trigger('change'); instead of options.push(opt);     where #mySelect2 is your select element id

Comment: could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [templateSelection](https://select2.org/selections#templating) option.

```js
$(".js-example-templating").select2({
    templateSelection: formatState,
});

function formatState(state) {
    return $(
        `<span class='tooltip' title='${state.title}'>${state.text}</span>`
    );
}
```

Edit: add `selectEle.append(opt);` before triggering change

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    data: {
        element_id: element_id,
        action: "get_preselect_values",
    },
}).then(function (data) {
    // var options = [];

    if (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, text) {
            var user_data =
                "<table> \
          <tr> \
            <td>Organisation</td> \
            <td>" +
                text[0][1] +
                "</td> \
          </tr> \
          <tr> \
            <td>Age</td> \
            <td>" +
                text[0][0] +
                "</td> \
          </tr> \
        </table>";

            var opt = new Option(text["text"], text["id"], true, true);
            opt.attr("title", user_data);
            // options.push(opt);
            selectEle.append(opt); // added codes
        });

        selectEle.trigger("change");
    }
    
});
```

Comment: Thanks @ikhvjs. I used this and working fine for current selection. But I would like to set `title` value of preselected values.

Comment: @ikvjs, could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2